Overload operator += for customString. How to right realization?
My realization have program then I try to += with empty initial string. I have the empty constructor = default.
Before I try something like:
str = "";
sz = 0;

This is also don't work.
My realization. Please can someone explain?
HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String() = default;

HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String(const HomyshenTH_String& s)
{
    str = s.str;
    sz = s.sz;
}

HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String(const char* ch)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (ch[length] != '\0') length++;
    str = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str[i] = ch[i];
    }
    sz = length;
}

HomyshenTH_String& HomyshenTH_String::operator+=(const HomyshenTH_String& s)
{
    size_t old_size = this->sz;
    this->sz = old_size + s.sz;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.sz; i++) {
        this->str[i + old_size] = s[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

HomyshenTH_String s("wordle");
const HomyshenTH_String s1("WORD");
s += s1; // works
s += "a"; // works
HomyshenTH_String MySubstr;
MySubstr += "a"; //error


How do you know that old_size + s.sz is less than the # of characters allocated in the buffer in operator+=. The code seems to assume that the str contains enough space without checking at all. Note that you may want to use a size and a capacity concept. Where the size is the number of valid characters and the capacity is the allocated size which may be larger than size but never smaller.

and then i need more memory i doubled the capacity, right? how to edit the solution by this fact? and this the reason why empty string += smth don't work?

Side issue: Your copy constructor also has an issue as it is shallow - it shares the memory owned by the object it is a copy of rather than acquiring its own memory for an independent copy. While you haven't seen it yet, this will cause problems in the future.

This little snippet suggests that you're not ready to implement your own string class. Use std::string, and it's append member or operator+=. There's a lot to cover about lifetime, resource management and finally memory management; it doesn't feet in a single post as an answer to a question. Pick a book on modern C++, and don't run ahead of yourself.

@AviBerger it's mean if i change desctrcutor from default to delete[] str, i have the error?

@lilof Yes and without delete[] it will leak memory. Anything you currently do to the str in one instance of HomyshenTH_String will affect the other instances pointing at the same char[].

Stop Teaching C by Kate Gregory (CppCon 2015), where she chastises professors for teaching C++ as if it were C.  And thereby giving students a horrible experience with C++, without learning how to program in C++.

Your copy constructor is not performing a deep copy of the character data. It is merely copying the str pointer as-is, thus breaking ownership of the data.  You end up with multiple instances of your class pointing at the same memory, with no clear indication of which instance actually owns the memory, so they will all try to free the same memory.
You are also not following the Rule of 3/5/0, as you lack a copy assignment operator, and apparently a destructor. You should also preferably implement a move constructor and move assignment operator, too.
Also, your concatenation operator is not expanding the allocated memory before copying characters into it.  You need to allocate a new memory block of sufficient size, copy the old data and the new data into the new memory, and then free the old memory.
Try something more like this:
class HomyshenTH_String {
private:
    char *str = nullptr;
    size_t sz = 0;

public:
    HomyshenTH_String() = default;

    HomyshenTH_String(const char* s);
    HomyshenTH_String(const HomyshenTH_String& s);
    HomyshenTH_String(HomyshenTH_String&& s);

    ~HomyshenTH_String();

    HomyshenTH_String& operator=(HomyshenTH_String s);

    HomyshenTH_String& operator+=(const char* s);
    HomyshenTH_String& operator+=(const HomyshenTH_String& s);
};

//#include <algorithm>
//#include <cstring>

static size_t str_length(const char* s) {
    //return s ? std::strlen(s) : 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    if (s) {
        while (s[length] != '\0') ++length;
    }
    return length;
}

static void str_copy(char* dest, const char* s, size_t sz) {
    //std::copy_n(s, sz, dest);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        dest[i] = s[i];
    }
}

static char* str_dupe(const char *s, size_t sz) {
    if (s == nullptr || sz == 0) return nullptr;
    char *new_str = new char[sz];
    str_copy(new_str, s, sz);
    return new_str;
}

static void str_concat(char* &dest, size_t &dest_sz, const char* s, size_t sz) {
    if (s == nullptr || sz == 0) return;
    size_t new_size = dest_sz + sz;
    char *new_str = new char[new_size];
    str_copy(new_str, dest, dest_sz);
    str_copy(new_str + dest_sz, s, sz);
    delete[] dest;
    dest = new_str;
    dest_sz = new_size;
}

HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String(const char* s)
{
    size_t length = str_length(s);
    str = str_dupe(s, length);
    sz = length;
}

HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String(const HomyshenTH_String& s)
{
    str = str_dupe(s.str, s.sz);
    sz = s.sz;
}

HomyshenTH_String::HomyshenTH_String(HomyshenTH_String&& s)
{
    //std::swap(str, s.str);
    //std::swap(sz, s.sz);
    str = s.str; s.str = nullptr
    sz = s.sz; s.sz = 0;
}

HomyshenTH_String::~HomyshenTH_String()
{
    delete[] str;
}

HomyshenTH_String& HomyshenTH_String::operator=(HomyshenTH_String s)
{
    //HomyshenTH_String temp(std::move(s));
    //std::swap(str, temp.str);
    //std::swap(sz, temp.sz);

    char *old_str = str;
    str = s.str; s.str = nullptr;
    sz = s.sz; s.sz = 0;
    delete[] old_str;

    return *this;
}

HomyshenTH_String& HomyshenTH_String::operator+=(const HomyshenTH_String& s)
{
    str_concat(str, sz, s.str, s.sz);
    return *this;
}

HomyshenTH_String& HomyshenTH_String::operator+=(const char* s) {
    str_concat(str, sz, s, str_length(s));
    return *this;
}


@jabaa Because this is clearly an exercise in writing a custom class that manages its own memory. In any case, it would make more sense to use std::vector instead of a smart pointer.

thanks for ur example, but i can't use   for realization

@lilof the standard functions I used are trivial to implement manually. Just replace them with your own logic. I have updated my example to show that.

i have one more question, in operator= in params we take copy of s, if this a copy, why we need to set s.str = nullptr and s.sz = 0;?

@lilof by passing the parameter by value, the operator supports both copy assignment and move assignment, letting the parameter's constructor differentiate, and then the operator can simply take ownership of the resulting str pointer. The parameter's str pointer has to be reset so the parameter's destructor doesn't free the memory we just took ownership of. The parameter must be left in a valid state. The old memory still needs to be freed, so you could also use s.str = old_str instead of nullptr and remove the explicit delete[], then the destructor will free the old memory for you.
